# Pass/Bind props to React Component which is obtained in form of object

Tags: reactjs

I have the following Object:

```
const iconsMap = {
    eye: <FaEye />,
    database: <FaDatabase />,
    reactjs: <FaReact />,

    linkedin: <AiFillLinkedin />,
    facebook: <AiFillFacebook />,
    instagram: <AiFillInstagram />,
    reddit: <AiFillRedditCircle />,
    email: <AiOutlineMail />,
};
```

I want to create a function that takes two arguments: `key` and `props` and based on the key, it returns the above props by spreading the `props` taken from the function:

Something like this:

```
export const getIcon = (iconName, props) => (<iconsMap[iconName] {...props }/>)
```

One possible way I found is:

```
export const getIcon = (iconName, props) => {
    switch (iconName) {
        case iconsMap.eye:
            return <FaEye {...props} />;
        case iconsMap.database:
            return <FaDatabase {...props} />;
        case iconsMap.reactjs:
            return <FaReact {...props} />;

        case iconsMap.linkedin:
            return <AiFillLinkedin {...props} />;
        case iconsMap.facebook:
            return <AiFillFacebook {...props} />;
        case iconsMap.instagram:
            return <AiFillInstagram {...props} />;
        case iconsMap.reddit:
            return <AiFillRedditCircle {...props} />;
        case iconsMap.email:
            return <AiOutlineMail {...props} />;

        default:
            return null;
    }
};
```

Though I am looking for an even more intuitive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping the React Node, map the function:

```
const iconsMap = {
  eye: FaEye,
  database: FaDatabase,
  ...
};
```

Then just invoke it with your props:

```
export const getIcon = (iconName, props) => {
  // Should be capitalized
  const Component = iconsMap[iconName];
  return <Component {...props}/>
};
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: After trying the solution you shared, I get this error: `Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <FaDatabase />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?`

Comment: Without seeing any code or how you use it I can't guess, either way it should be a separate new question